# How can I send MMS to emulator using adb command?

Tags: android, android-mms

I am developing an Android message application. For that I need to integrate SMS, MMS features. I followed this blog to implement the features (here is the blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).

But now I want to test SMS send/receive using Android tools. But I am not able to send or receive MMS using Emulator. How can I receive MMS using `DDMS or adb` or any other tools?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use emulator to send mms.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/RELEASENOTES.html